# Bound on solutions of $Ax \ge b$

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, linear-algebra, linear-programming

Let $A \in \mathbb{Z}^{m \times n}, b \in \mathbb{Z}^{m \times 1}$.

One can show that if there is a solution of $Ax \ge b, x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ then there is one such that $\|x\|_{\infty} \le c (\|A\|_{\infty} m)^m \|b\|_{\infty}$.

Which other kind of bounds are known on the solutions of such systems?

Comment: $b$ lies in $\mathbb Z^m$, right?

Comment: @AnthonyQuas yes, fixed

Comment: As a special case, this would imply that if $A$ has nonnegative entries, then $Ax\ge b$ has no nonnegative solution unless $b$ is nonpositive, which is obviously nonsense.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek yes, fixed